# Animation view in Dymola doesn't show pictures

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am working on a Modelica mechanical model which includes `Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Visualizers.FixedShape` build animation, but when using this component in a trivial model, there is nothing in the animation view, but when using it in a complicated model, the animation view works fine.

The following screenshots are based on the [example from Claytex blog](https://www.claytex.com/blog/fun-with-dice/), the model could be downloaded from [this link here](https://www.claytex.com/blog/fun-with-dice/)
My question is why the animation view doesn't show the picture in the trivial model?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting as an answer, as pictures are not possible in comments:

For me, the dice is visible simulating "JustImage" using Dymola 2021/2021x. It is just pretty small and in the origin. If the view isn't rotated it hides behind the axis arrowhead...

[image: Dymola Animation View]

Comment: And if you look at the question you see that Claytex sets r_shape as well as image, and that seems to be missed for the dice.